# Which law of physics is applicable for communication?

Tags: electronics, electrical-engineering, technology

1. What is the physics behind communication like internet, mobile phones etc.
2. What are the equations?

Comment: If we are talking about modern communication devices then surely it is the physics of electronics of course. And some wave physics. And some acoustics. Isn't this question a little broad?

Comment: I think that this is way too broad for anything useful. On the one hand, you have electrodynamics and especially the physics needed for sending and receiving electromagnetic waves. Then there is optics for using optical fibres, etc. There is the whole field of electronics in order to process information for communication and there is information theory to provide a background for coding, error correction, etc. The latter is not strictly physical, but there is physics in identifying noise, etc.

Comment: Maxwell's equation of electromagnetism for signal propagation in optic fiber(internet) and wave propagation in free space( for mobile phones). Electronics is also very important as for the signal treatment, modulation, mulitplexing ...